# How to upload an array of objects where some objects contain files using MERN stack application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, multer

I have flowing galleryContent array in React state which has some objects and some of the objects contain files so how can I upload this array to the backend?

```
state = {
    galleryContent: [
      { type: "image", image: File, isPrimary: false },
      { type: "video", video: File, isPrimary: false },
      { type: "audio", audio: File, isPrimary: false },
      { type: "youtube", url: "https://youtu.be/ctvlUvN6wSE", isPrimary: true },
      { type: "youtube", url: "https://youtu.be/ctvlUvN6wSE", isPrimary: false },
      {
        type: "soundcloud",
        url:
          "https://soundcloud.com/saddam-mamoon/na_bola_moner_kotha_by_saddam-bangla-song-2015",
        isPrimary: false
      },
      {
        type: "youtube",
        url: "https://youtu.be/ctvlUvN6wSE",
        isPrimary: false
      },
      { type: "youtube", url: "https://youtu.be/ctvlUvN6wSE", isPrimary: false }
    ]
  };
```

It was so easy to upload as JSON data if there wasn't any file in objects.
If I upload files using form data then I can't upload associated data(like type and isPrimary) with the files

NB: I want to upload all of the galleryContent array data in a single request. And you can suggest any articles regarding this issue

Comment: Where do you want to save your file like AWS s3 or in server

Comment: @Nane in server

Comment: Ok then this strategy will work 1) send this array to the backend. 2) loop the array find image, audio, video objects save it on your server (you can use ```express-fileupload```) 3) get the files URL to replace it with the array in the appropiate places 4) Now you have a complete array ready to be saved in you DB..

Comment: @ShifutHossain How did you finally achieve this? I have a similar use case. I am thinking of sending two different arrays, one for files and the other for file data like isPrimary, etc. at the same index. Is there a way to send the data in a single object? The other way I think this can be achieved is by converting the image to a blob on my own and then sending it in the object. Any thoughts on this?